# Recursion Theorem, Enderton, Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic

This question concerns the proof of Recursion Theorem found on page 39 of Enderton’s *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic*. Being that the proof is quite dense and involves notation previously, elaborated in the book, I intend to ask this to an audience who is familiar with the text.

The Theorem is as follows:

Assume that the subset $C$ of $U$ is freely generated from $B$ by $f$ and $g$, where 
$$f: U\times U \to U$$
And
$$g:U\to U$$
Further assume that $V$ is a set and $F$, $G$, and $h$ functions such that 
$$h: B\to V$$
$$F: V\times V \to V$$
$$G: V\to V$$
Then there is a unique function 
$$\bar h : C \to V$$
Such that
I) For $x\in B$, $\bar h (x)=h(x)$

II) For $x,y\in C$,
$$\bar h (f(x,y))=F(\bar h (x), \bar h (y))$$
$$\bar h (g(x))=G(\bar h (x))$$

Enderton states that the proof is “set-theoretic” and at the beginning of the proof, Enderton makes the following distinction:

“$v$ is [an] acceptable [function] if the domain of $v$ is a subset of $C$, the range a subset of $V$, and for any $x$ and $y$ in $C$:

i’) If $x$ belongs to $B$ and to the domain of $v$, then $v(x)=h(x)$.

(ii’) If $f(x,y)$ belongs to the domain of $v$, then so do $x$ and $y$, and $v(f(x,y))=F(v(x),v(y))$. If $g(x)$ belongs to the domain of $v$, then so does $x$, and $v(g(x))=G(v(x))$.

Let $K$ be the collection of all acceptable functions, and let $\bar h = \cup K$, the union of all the acceptable functions...”

Essentially, the proof continues to show that $\bar h$ is that unique function of which we claimed exists.

My question concerns the existence of each acceptable $v$: **what guarantees the existence of any acceptable $v$?** The only justification I could conceive would involve the fact that $f,g,h,F,G$ are functions whose domains are already defined. So to say that Enderton’s choice of $v$ really involves taking “values” or “pieces” of each already defined function that match the required criteria. Still, I do not know if this is the right way to justify the existence of such $v$ and for that matter, if we are always guaranteed to find points of each function that match each criteria...

Comment: Won't the empty function be acceptable?

Comment: I would suggest you first understand how the proof of the recursion theorem works on the simpler case of the naturals... in particular the aspect in question where it is proved by induction that "approximations" (i.e. acceptable functions) exist with domain any initial segment of $\mathbb N.$ Once you have that down and and understand the connection between recursion on the naturals and this slightly different setting (an abstract version of recursion on formula structure), it will be easy to see how the idea generalizes

Comment: Thank you, I am doing that right now!

Comment: The author has defined function $\overline h$ from $f,g,F,g$ and $h$. Thus, we have it; what is necessary to do is prove the uniqueness (i.e. that the definition is correct).